# Why does my Qt5 app (and qt-creator) fail to display certain exotic unicode characters

Tags: qt, unicode, qt5

I am developing a Qt5 based app that needs to display exotic unicode characters in a QTreeView. However, I am suffering inconsistent behaviour that I just cannot understand.

```
U+1F55B CLOCK FACE TWELVE OCLOCK
```

displays OK.

```
U+1F9C0 CHEESE WEDGE
```

does not display correctly, it appears as a vertical white rectangle.

The treeview's data is supplied by a class derived from QAbstractItemModel. If I save this data to a text file (via QTextStream) and then view this file via the terminal then the cheese wedge appears correctly. I can thus be certain that internally (in the model) it is stored correctly; the problem is that it is not displayed in the treeview.

I notice that in Qt-Creator editor I have the same problem. U+1F55B (clock face) displays correctly,  U+1F9C0 (cheese wedge) appears as a vertical white rectangle.

This does not seem to be font related. In my text editor (Geany), the selected font "DejaVu Sans Condensed" 9 point shows the cheese wedge correctly. The same font in both my app and Qt-creator does not show the cheese wedge. I have tried multiple fonts that do support the cheese wedge but my Qt app (nor Qt-creator) ever show the cheese.

I tried another Qt5 editor, "FeatherPad", and found that this also does not display the cheese wedge correctly. I am wondering if this is a Qt5 issue? If this is a Qt5 issue, then just knowing a way of detecting which characters cannot be displayed would be extremely useful; I can then replace them with the replacement character.

I am running XFCE on XUbuntu 20.04.

Comment: Can you show code of how you're trying to display them?

Comment: My app uses the Qt model/view framework. So to display data I 
overload QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data and return a QString (obviously the QString gets converted to a QVariant). It would be very difficult to show you more code as it is a large complex application and multiple functions are called to achieve the above. But the main point to make is that I do not believe this to be an issue with my code. The exact same problem is present in qt-creator editor and another qt based editor "Featherpad". The problem does not show in non-qt apps I tried (geany, mousepad, gnome- terminal).

Comment: I'm not asking for your "large complex application". I'm asking for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't want to see a description of your code. We want to see actual code that we can try out ourselves.

Comment: OK I will do that. But it will take me some time to cut down my project in order to produce the example. In the meantime, if you want to see the problem, just fire up qt-creator editor or Featherpad and paste unicode characters U+1F55B and U+1F9C0. You will see the clock but you wont see the cheese. If you can explain that then you will likely have solved my problem.

Comment: Turns out that this is nothing to do with my application. It is a problem that effects all Qt apps running on a default install of XUbuntu20.04. The problem can be resolved by uninstalling all Noto fonts. This may be  overkill; it might be that just one "problematic" font needs to be uninstalled. Apparently, Qt apps cannot display colour emojis. So if Noto is providing a colour cheese wedge, then only the white rectangle is displayed. Remove noto fonts, and qt apps display the grey cheese wedge. See  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-meta/+bug/1766976